# Dynamically encrypting web.config using aspnet_regiis in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config, console-application

I was trying to centralize web.config/app.config using one utility tool. I am able to transform all app.config files in any folder but i am stuck with web.config. Seems webconfigurationmanager will not work outside virtual directory. So i was trying to implement aspnet_regiis encrypt- decryption method in my tool.

```
private void RunProcess(string processName, string arguments)
    {
        var newProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(processName);
        //Log("User: " + GetSystemName());

        if (null != arguments && arguments.Any())
        {
            newProcess.Arguments = arguments;
            newProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;
            newProcess.ErrorDialog = true;
            newProcess.RedirectStandardError = true;
            newProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            newProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
        }
        using (var proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo = newProcess;
            proc.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

private void Encrypt(string path)
    {
        string framework = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe";

        if (8 == IntPtr.Size
            || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))
            framework = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe";


        RunProcess(framework, " -pef \"connectionStrings\"  \"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\somefolder\" –prov \"DataProtectionConfigurationProvider\"");
    }
```

My doubt is

> " -pef \"connectionStrings\"  \"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\somefolder\"
>   –prov \"DataProtectionConfigurationProvider\""

I am sure i am making some mistake over here the command simply not executing. Its giving me aspnet_regiis help options.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake. it seems c# does not need a provider at all . I changed it to

> " -pef \"connectionStrings\" \"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\somefolder\""

and voila! it succeeded.